# Spring boot. Reading MANIFEST.MF using jcabi manifests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, manifest.mf, jcabi

I'm trying to add AppName and Version to actuator's **/info** endpoint using **jcabi-manifests** https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-manifests library. Code snippet is below:

```
@Component
public class VersionInfoContributor implements InfoContributor {

@Override
public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
    String artifactName = Manifests.read("Artifact-Name");

    builder.withDetail("Artifact-Name", artifactName);
}
```

Artifact-Name is set in build.gradle file next way:

```
jar {
   manifest {
        attributes("Artifact-Name": "TestActuator")
    }
}
```

The attribute IS present in **META-INF/MANIFEST.MF** file inside result .jar file but when trying to access **/info** endpoint getting error: 
Attribute 'Artifact-Name' not found in MANIFEST.MF file(s) among 46 other attribute(s)

I know there is **BuildProperties** bean in Spring-boot actuator but won't like idea to expose all these fields - AppName and Version more than enough.

Comment: Try to turn logging ON to see what attributes are visible

Comment: "Agent-Class", "Ant-Version", "Archiver-Version", "Automatic-Module-Name", "Bnd-LastModified", "Boot-Class-Path", "Build-Jdk", "Build-Timestamp", "Built-By", "Bundle-Description", "Bundle-DocURL", "Bundle-License", "Bundle-ManifestVersion",etc. Inside Manifests.append(Mf streams) there are 58 stream fetched. A lot of them are coming from jdk, some from spring-boot libraries but there is no stream from my .jar.

Comment: It seems that your JAR is not on the classpath at the time of calling `Manifests.read()`. Most likely it's loaded later, by Spring. Not sure how it works exactly in Spring.